# How to compare 2 ordinal distributions?

Tags: distributions, ordinal-data

A sample answered a dichotomous question and were rated twice on an ordinal scale (high, medium, low), using 2 different rating methods (the question did not influence the ratings).

The results can be visualized in a table like this:

Rating method 1 Question answer

```
                 Yes    No      Total
High            
Medium          
Low         
Total
```

Rating method 2 Question answer

```
                  Yes   No      Total
High            
Medium          
Low         
Total
```

I want to see if the ratings' distribution in each method are different from each other.
A.  What statistical test can I use to analyze the results?
B.  Should I use an statistical test for dependent groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use the $X^2$ or ***Fisher's Exact*** test.  However, note that Fisher's is limited to two groups. I would suggest to apply and evaluate both - as they will likely point to the same result (depending on your data). If your a Python user there is an intuitive example of ***[chi2_continency](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html)*** and ***[Fisher's](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html)*** using counts of Whales and Sharks between Atlantic and Pacific Oceans.

See also, [Hazra, 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4966396/):

*The Pearson's χ2 test is the most commonly used test for assessing difference in distribution of a categorical variable between two or more independent groups. If the groups are ordered in some manner, the χ2 test for trend should be used. The Fisher's exact probability test is a test of the independence between two dichotomous categorical variables. It provides a better alternative to the χ2 statistic to assess the difference between two independent proportions when numbers are small, but cannot be applied to a contingency table larger than a two-dimensional one.*

Comment: Thanks. Are you suggesting a 3-way (method1 X method2 X answer) X2  or Fisher's Exact test?

Comment: You can input your raw data (2*3) into X2 contingency. For Fishers, you are limited to 2*2 contingency table - and might be desirable if your sample sizes are low. But X2 should be ok if your samples are large enough (+25 in each class).

Comment: @user3315563 can you comment or mark as accepted please?